# I want navigator.webdrivers set false or undefined in selenium.firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want `navigator.webdrivers` set false or undefined in `selenium.firefox`.

Geckodriver version : 0.30.0
Firefox version : 95.0.2
Selenium version : 4.1.0

This problem's solution in Chrome.

```
Coptions = new ChromeOptions();
Coptions.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
```

but it is not working on Firefox.

My tries(*failure*):

```
Ooptions = new FirefoxOptions();
Ooptions.SetPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", false);
Ooptions.SetPreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
Ooptions.SetPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false);
```